# Solidity Constructor Question

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, remix

I have a Contract Template (Say contract ABC).  The constructor takes in 3 fields to initialize a contract.   I built in logic within the constructor to return a bool based on data checks.   The constructor should fail and not create a valid Contract if the data fields fails validation.  The return is a bool.

function ABC(bytes32 _field1, bytes32 _field2, bytes32 _field3) returns (bool isSuccess);

Now when I try to create a new contract (from another contract):  How do I check for the bool (Success).

I create an instance of the contract as:

ABC local = new ABC(_field1, _field2, _field3);

Is there a way to check if this was success - based on the bool return from the Constructor.

Alternative 1: I can do the data checks before I send the request to the Constructor.   I was trying to avoid rewriting the same code in multiple locations.

Alternative 2: I can initialize a field isValue within the constructor and check for it when validating an instance.

Any advise?  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, its worth noting that if something throws or causes an error the contract creation will automatically fail. If it does fail, you won't be able to return `false` anyways since all state is reverted.

Because of this, its best to simply use `require` or `assert` statements to throw if data is invalid which will cease contract creation and invalid contracts will never be created.

Alternative 1: I would recommend doing this anyways so you don't waste gas. Contract creation currently costs $5+ USD which will be wasted if you don't.

Alternative 2: You could do this, but this in inefficient since this stored data isn't actually needed.